# How to use Inverted Commas in Full Text Search in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2017

I have implemented full text search on SQL server 2017 and it works fine using AND, OR, NOT queries. I need to search for a text "**John Doe**" as a complete text. If I enter it using inverted commas, it fails.

**EDIT 1**

I tried `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CONTAINS (colName,'"John Doe"')` and it says `Incorrect value near colName`

Can someone help?

Comment: My guess is that SQL Server stripped off those inverted commas when it built the full text index.  [See here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be3b80a1-9b7c-4a2c-8be1-92390b38a835/full-text-search-and-punctuation-marks?forum=sqldatabaseengine) for some possible workarounds.

Comment: Inverted commas are not part of the column. I want to do a search so that it returns records with an exact match of John Doe

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (see *<simple_term>*) `CONTAINS(YourColumn,'"John Doe"')` would work. What did you actually try, as you haven't actually shown your attempts (just described them). You said it fails, so what was the error?

Comment: @Larnu added code and error

Comment: CAn you provide your full SQL statement please?

Comment: @Larnu my bad, there was an error in the sql statement. Got ti fixed. Do we have any handy link explaining all queries that we can use full-text?